# Scope resolution in c++

Tags: c++, oop

I have a program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    virtual void Output() {
        cout << "A";
    }
 
};

class B :public A {
public:
    A::Output();

    void Output() {
        cout << " B ";
    }
};
int main() {
    A* a = new B;
    a->Output();
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why the line "A::outPut()" has an error. Please help me with this question.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `A::Output();` in `B`?

Comment: Because, within the definition of class `B`, the line `A::Output()` declares the function `A::Output()`, which is a member of class `A`.    The class `A` is the only class permitted to declare member functions of class `A`.    If class `B` (or any other class) was permitted to declare member functions of class `A`, then class `A` would have no control over what member functions it has.

Comment: @Peter If i write the line "A::Output()" in function Output, it's oke

Comment: @NathanOliver This is multiple choice question about output of the program

Comment: You can *call* `A::Output()` from within `B::Output()`. That's actually not uncommon, even if it has gone a bit out of fashion in the past 20 years or so: B uses functionality provided by A, and amends it (typical with inheritance chains like "employee" -> "manager" -> "CEO"). But then it must be in `B::Output`'s body, not somewhere in the middle of the class definition of B (where it is interpreted as a declaration which it is not).

Comment: @AnLê   So?  Like many code constructs in C++, the line `A::Output()` means different things in different contexts.   Within the definition of class `B` it is an invalid declaration.   Within the definition of `B::Output()` it has the effect of calling `A::Output()` (as long as `A::Output()` is not `private`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When used in a method of a subclass of `A`, the `A::Output()` is an expression calling the `Output` method from the `A` class. As any other executable expression, it can only be use inside a method and not in the class body. Because the class body should only contain declarations (and definitions). For example, you cannot call functions at a class body level.